# Spectrum of primitive nonnegative integer matrices

Tags: nt.number-theory, matrices, algebraic-number-theory, nonnegative-matrices

Let $P(X) = a_nX^n + \cdots + a_1X + a_0$ with $a_i \in \mathbb Z$.

> **Question 1.** Is there an efficient criterion on the $a_i$ to decide if there exists a primitive nonnegative integer matrix with characteristic polynomial **equal** to $P(X)$?
>   [$M$ is *primitive* if $M^k$ is positive for some $k \geq 0$.]
>
> **Question 2.** Given such a polynomial, is there an **efficient** method to enumerate the valid matrices?

Some remarks.

- An answer in the particular case $a_n = a_0 = 1$ will also make me happy. The polynomials I'm interested in are typically a product of a Perron number and roots of unity, for example $(X^3-X-1)(X-1)^k$.
- A similar question, *"What algebraic numbers are eigenvalues of nonnegative integer matrices?"*, is answered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/112218/eigenvalues-of-nonnegative-integer-matrices), but I want all the roots of $P(X)$ and no other eigenvalues in the candidate matrices.
- There seems to be many variants of this problem ([example](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2000-13-04/S0894-0347-00-00342-8/)), sorry if this question was already answered somewhere.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you do the case $n=2$?

Comment: It would be fascinating to obtain a criterion, let alone an efficient one. Do you permit adding extra zeros as eigenvalues (that is, replacing $p$ by $X^k p$)? Over the reals, it is possible to do this (with criteria in terms of traces of powers, see Boyle & Handelman  cited in the reference you cited). 

Note that $(x-2)(x-1)$ cannot be realized (in your strong sense), but $x(x-2)(x-1)$ can. Reference is another paper by Mike B and me, *Algebraic shift equivalence and primitive matrices,* tams (1993), which deals mostly with realization over the nonnegative integers.

Comment: David, unfortunately I would like to avoid the additional zero eigenvalues. Is this question open even without the primitivity assumption? Thanks for the very interesting articles!

Comment: Gerry, I haven't looked at it for hours but it doesn't seem to be obvious even for $2\times2$ matrices.

Comment: Right now the best I can do is to enumerate all the matrices (using the trace constraint) and test them one by one... Can anyone think of a less stupid approach?

Answer (score 2):

Torre-Mayo et al. [MR2350690 Torre-Mayo, J.; Abril-Raymundo, M. R.; Alarcia-Estévez, E.; Marijuán, C.; Pisonero, M. [The nonnegative inverse eigenvalue problem from the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial. EBL digraphs.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379507002674)  *Linear Algebra Appl.* 426 (2007), no. 2-3, 729–773] solved the following problem when $n=4$: "given $k_1$,$k_2$,$\dots$,$k_n$ real numbers, find necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of a nonnegative matrix $A$ of order $n$ with characteristic polynomial $x^n+k_1 x^{n-1}+k_2x^{n-2}a+\cdots+k_n$".